# Get-FileMetaData Splitting of Path

Tags: powershell

I am using the below to pull through metadata from a file structure I am reading. I am also wanting to split out the `Name` field to just include the filename without extension. I would use `BaseName` but i'm not leveraging `Get-ChildItem` so this isn't possible. How would I use `PSPath -split` or something similar to put this value in a new column against each file? This is looping through a bunch of files then exporting to a txt file.

```
Get-FileMetaData  -folders 'C:|Pics' -properties Name, Path, Comments, Dimensions, Width, Height | Sort-Object Name |
    select Name, Path, Comments, Dimensions, Width, Height | Export-Csv '\\nzsdf01\SCRIPTS\test.txt' -encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Well, you can add `BaseName` property inside that function by [stripping the extension from Name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12503910).

Comment: I meant you can edit the code of the function. Otherwise use calculated properties in `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the code from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42933461/) your options are:

1. modify the function to also include BaseName

   ```
   $hash.Clear()
   $hash.BaseName = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file.Name)
   ```

   and specify BaseName in the parameters for the function:

   ```
   Get-FileMetaData -folders 'r:\foo' -properties BaseName, Path, Comments
   ```
2. use calculated properties in `select`

   ```
   Get-FileMetaData -folders 'r:\foo' -properties Name, Path, Comments |
       select @{N='BaseName'; E={[IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name)}}, 
           Path, Comments | .........
   ```

Comment: Was so close with the properties. Thanks again for the help!